# Object Was Open Error in recordset - MYSQL VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have a code in vba that connects in MySQL. My query returns 1M+ records and store it in recordset.

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
rst.Open strSql, mysqlConnection, adOpenStatic
```

At first, I I tried only a few records and it works fine. However when I tried 1M+ records, Is says the object was open.

How will I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code? I doubt we will find the root cause just with these two lines

Comment: I think it is the same problem that I have. I have a possible solution however would need to see your code to check if it is. I would need to see how you open the connection and open the recordset

Comment: I agree with @R3uK, your description makes very little to no sense, and the code you provided seems logically correct so this might not be a problem. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment - so will have to write this as an answer. It sounds like you haven't closed off your recordset and connections after the first use - so its confused by your request to open them again.

You would need a statement like:

```
rst.close
mysqlConnection.close
```

after you have run the query in the lines displayed.

If you haven't closed off, you might want to write these at the top just for the next time then move them down.

Apologies if you have already tried this - but this struck me as a possible 
cause and something I came across when initially working with ODBC objects

Comment: do i really need to close the connection too ?

Comment: Hi san-san, It depends if you are doing any more with it, each time a macro runs and for each SQL communication, I tend to open and close the connection. Once I have the recordset data I want, I close the recordset too. Otherwise you are repeatedly opening the connection - which you can't do

Comment: should connection be closed too after opening the recordset?

Comment: hi, this is my code..

       On Error GoTo error_handler
       rst.Open strSql, sqlConn, adOpenStatic
       On Error GoTo 0

      error_handler:
       msgbox err.description

while executing the query, it goes to my error handler after liekly 2 minutes and says that "Object was open" though i havent called other recordset before.

Comment: i just want to ask, what is the difference between

rst.Open strSql, mySqlConnection, adOpenStatic

and 

Set rst = mysqlConnection.Execute(strSql)

Comment: I'm not an expert however, I tend to use Execute for working only the SQL - whereas I tend to use rst.Open or similar when working with recordsets.

I cannot really see much of the code in the above text so I don't think I can offer any assistance there. It sounds like it could be an open connection hanging or it could be an issue caused by a slow connection possibly - if you are using very large files over a slow connection

Answer (score 0):

The first code I had was like this:

```
Call MySqlConnectionOpen
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
rst.Open sqlQuery, mysqlConnection, adOpenStatic
 ...copy records
rst.Close
Set rst=Nothing
Call MySqlConnectionClose
```

then I changed it to:

```
Call MySqlConnectionOpen
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
Set rst = MySqlConn.Execute(sqlQuery)
 ...copy records
rst.Close
Set rst=Nothing
call mysqlConnectionClose
```

and fortunately it worked.